# Accessing a html file on a server through Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, ftp, webserver

Problem Description:

I have a problem at work where I should create a link to a html page which shows public data related to the customer.

`www.example.com/content/user_123456/output.html`

After I upload a user's data `user_123456` folder to the /content/ directory.

```
style.css
main.js
```

The `user_123456` folder contains linked styles and linked javascript

Expected Output:

When I load `www.example.com/content/user_123456/output.html` in a Web Browser I expect it to load the html page and the linked styles and javascript. Instead it shows me an error that indicates the directory is not visible.

Tested:

I have tried uploading images to the directory `www.example.com/content/user_123456/image01.jpg` and they load just fine in the browser so it can not be directory visibility problem.

I realise this is a broad question, but I want to estimate the technical cost of solving this problem and it would go a long way to understand the undertaking of such a solution.

Questions:

- What is different about serving html files in comparison to jpg
  files?
- What needs to be done in a broad manner that the file functions the
  way I expect it to?

Comment: That 100% depends on the web server you are running and how it is configured. So we really need that information to help -- there is not much of a point in speculating. Are you maintaining the web server? it sounds like it's a black box to you and you may not even have access to it (on disk)?

Comment: It already helps to know it can be configured in a way to allow my intended functionality. All my current understanding allows me to say is that it is configured to serve Typo3 CMS.

Comment: I do not have access to the server itself, just the content folder through SFTP. I can however tell the developers on the server side to configure the server accordingly. I want to understand what a possible implementation on a random web server could look like to be able to understand what I could potentially be looking at in terms of expense. A disclaimer on the ease of implementation would be appreciated though.

Comment: What is the exact error message in the console?

Comment: You keep saying "expense". There is no expense here. This is trivial. The web admin just needs to add static file serving from that folder you writing to, and allow you to write to it.

Comment: turns out html files were also enabled but I ended up figuring a way through the CMS system and not direct HTML file loading. Thanks for the helps.